# UIWebView loading stuff in AJAX blocks the main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using a webview in a modal viewController that loads a page. The page can take up to 10sec to load its content in AJAX.

If a dismiss the modal viewController after the page is fully loaded, everything looks good. However, if I dismiss the modal viewController while the page is loading, the UI is completely locked. I paused in debug while the UI was locked, here is what's happening in the main thread:

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x390b6fa8 in __psynch_mutexwait ()
#1  0x3911bf50 in _pthread_mutex_lock ()
#2  0x366ac60c in _WebTryThreadLock(bool) ()
#3  0x366ad434 in WebThreadLock ()
#4  0x31151cf8 in -[UIWebView dealloc] ()
#5  0x30f2f9b2 in -[UIView dealloc] ()
#6  0x30f2f9b2 in -[UIView dealloc] ()
#7  0x38b04022 in (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) ()
#8  0x2e6de1c8 in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop ()
#9  0x2e773e82 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#10 0x2e6de470 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#11 0x2e6de252 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#12 0x334182ea in GSEventRunModal ()
#13 0x30f93844 in UIApplicationMain ()
#14 0x00017074 in main at /Users/.../main.m:16
```

The UI freezes for approximatively 10sec, which is the exact time the page needs to load.

I tried calling [_webview stopLoading] before dismissing the modal view controller but it does not help.

Does anyone know what is happening here and what I should do to prevent the webview to freeze the UI? Thanks

Comment: Having the same issue. Cant seem to figure it out either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was some CSS properties causing this freeze. So if you have the same issue, and if you are lucky enough to have access to the page behind your UIWebView, try to comment some CSS properties until you find the one causing the webView to freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling -stopLoading on the UIWebView before you call dismiss on your view controller.

Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stopLoading

Comment: Please read my post entirely: I already explained that calling stopLoading before dismissing my view controller does not help